# Unexpected output from the mapper. It adds a number before the output

Tags: java, hadoop

So I am giving my Mapper an input from another MapReduce job. Here I had done some partitioning of my input so that the reducer iterable doesn't go out of memory (This is just a test program). So in the mapper I just was just trying to remove the '/' in input and then add the total sum in the reducer but the mapper started giving an unusual output where it added an integer before the output, whereas the rest of the output is also not as expected. 
 Also prior to this I was getting errors like expected `'org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable'` and adding this `' job1.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
    job1.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);'` avoided the errors.

Excuse me if I am terribly wrong somewhere.

```
package test;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
public class MapCom2
{
    public static class Map1 extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable();
    private Text word = new Text();
    public static int cnt=1;
    public void map1(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {
        String line = value.toString();
        Configuration conf=context.getConfiguration();
        String []tokens=line.split("\t");
        int l=0;
        while(l<tokens.length)
            {
            if(tokens[l].contains("/"))
                break;
            l=l+1;
            }
        int indno=tokens[l].lastIndexOf("/");
        String w=tokens[l].substring(0,indno);
        int tcnt=Integer.parseInt(tokens[l+1]);
        word.set(w);
        one.set(tcnt);
        context.write(word,one);
        }
    }

    public static int main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf1= new Configuration();
    Job job1 = new Job(conf1,"mapcom2");
    job1.setJarByClass(test.MapCom2.class);
    job1.setJobName("mapcom2");
    job1.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
    job1.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job1.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job1.setMapperClass(Map1.class);
    //job1.setReducerClass(Reduce1.class);
    String op=args[0];
    if(!(op.charAt(op.length()-1)+"").equals("/"))
        op=op+"/"+"part-r-00000";
    else
        op=op+"part-r-00000";
    job1.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job1.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job1, new Path(op));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, new Path(args[1]));
    int ret=job1.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1;
    return ret;
    }
}
```

The input is this.

```
)hadoop/0   1
-C/0    1
-classpath/0    1
-cvf/0  1
-d/0    1
-mkdir/0    2
-put/0  2
./0 1
/home/hadoop/hadoop/0   1
/home/hadoop/hadoopAssign/wordcount_classes/0   1
/wordcount/input/0  3
/wordcount/output/0 1
1)/0    1
2)/0    1
3)/0    1
4)/0    1
5/0 1
Assign/hadoop-core-1.1.2.jar/0  1
WordCount.java/0    1
and/0   1
copy/0  1
file01/0    2
file02/0    2
files/0 1
fs/0    3
fs/1    2
hadoop/0    3
hadoop/1    2
jar/0   2
javac/0 1
make/0  1
mkdir/0 1
org.myorg.WordCount/0   1
them/0  1
to/0    2
two/0   1
wordcount.jar/0 2
wordcount/0 1
wordcount/input/0   1
wordcount_classes//0    1
wordcount_classes/0 1
```

whereas the output is this

```
0   )hadoop/0   1
12  -C/0    1
19  -classpath/0    1
34  -cvf/0  1
43  -d/0    1
50  -mkdir/0    2
61  -put/0  2
70  ./0 1
76  /home/hadoop/hadoop/0   1
100 /home/hadoop/hadoopAssign/wordcount_classes/0   1
148 /wordcount/input/0  3
169 /wordcount/output/0 1
191 1)/0    1
198 2)/0    1
205 3)/0    1
212 4)/0    1
219 5/0 1
225 Assign/hadoop-core-1.1.2.jar/0  1
258 WordCount.java/0    1
277 and/0   1
285 copy/0  1
294 file01/0    2
305 file02/0    2
316 files/0 1
326 fs/0    3
333 fs/1    2
340 hadoop/0    3
351 hadoop/1    2
362 jar/0   2
370 javac/0 1
380 make/0  1
389 mkdir/0 1
399 org.myorg.WordCount/0   1
423 them/0  1
432 to/0    2
439 two/0   1
447 wordcount.jar/0 2
465 wordcount/0 1
479 wordcount/input/0   1
499 wordcount_classes//0    1
522 wordcount_classes/0 1
```

expected output for first few lines would be like

```
)hadoop 1
-C  1
-classpath  1
-cvf    1
```

This is just what I am trying to do but the problem is in the above program.
what my final goal was to limit the size of value iterable in Reducer. where for words hadoop and fs we would get output as 5 and 5 . Here I've limited the reducer values to 3 by partitioning the mapper somehow but I'm getting stuck in my mapper.So /0, /1 ,/2 are just denoting that for example word 'hadoop' has occurred 3 times already and so we move to hadoop/1 .This was done in the preceding map reduce program which I'am going to linear chain later on.  Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a really hadoop's expert, but shouldn't you implement the *map* method and not call it *map1*?

Comment: I knew I had done something very silly here and was looking for it. Thanks to have pointed out

Comment: I just don't know when and why I changed the map method name and that was the reason for such output. Thanks @AlessandroSuglia . Should I delete this question, I feel stupid. Thanks

Comment: I'll put an answer here in order to grant to others to learn from your experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Hadoop framework the map phase is assigned to a *mapper job*. This one is associated to a specific interface that you need to implement: *Mapper*.

This interface has a unique method called *map* which is what you need to implement in order to correctly implement the map phase.

In your code there is a typo (*map1*). Correcting it the user has solved its problem.